# Android Material Snackbar Old Style

Tags: android, material-design, android-styles, android-snackbar

Since Android Studio 4.1 the `Snackbar` is in a new style (from the built-in Material library):

[image]

But I still prefer the old style:

[image]

How to achieve that? I've searched around the internet but still can't find the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Snackbars can span the entire width of the screen only when a UI does not use persistent navigation components like app bars or bottom navigation bars.
> Snackbars that span the entire width of a UI can push only FABs up when they appear.

Since I don't have your code you can try setting the style of `Snackbar` by adding this line in your AppTheme in styles.xml or themes.xml:

```
<item name="snackbarStyle">@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Snackbar.FullWidth</item>
```

Or programmatically you can try this:

```
// Create the Snackbar
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(containerLayout, "", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
// Get the Snackbar's layout view
Snackbar.SnackbarLayout layout = (Snackbar.SnackbarLayout) snackbar.getView();
//If the view is not covering the whole snackbar layout, add this line
layout.setPadding(0,0,0,0);
// Show the Snackbar
snackbar.show();
```

Comment: Is there any way to show the new style snackbars programmatically with a similar approach?

Comment: @Alix I don't get it, why can't you? You can simply add snackbar programmatically with only the first line of my code above and then show it.

Comment: Apparantly I didn't inherit the proper material theme. Changing theme solved it for me.

Comment: <item name="snackbarStyle">@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Snackbar.FullWidth</item> did the job for me.THanks.